# Run-Time Check Failure #2 Error for All My Variables

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

My program runs fine but after I chose to quit, it gives me *"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'col' was corrupted."* Thought it also said that about ALL my variables.

All I want to know is how I can I fix whatever is going on.

My main:

```
    int main()
{
    int row, col;
    double revenue = 0;
    char choice;
    char seats[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
    int tickets_sold = 0;

    double prices[MAX_ROWS] = { 40, 40, 35, 35, 35, 30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 9.5, 9.5 };

    for (int rows = 0; rows < MAX_COLS; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < MAX_COLS; cols++)
        {
            seats[rows][cols] = '*';
        }
    }

    do
    {
        menu();
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == '1')
            display(seats, tickets_sold, revenue);

        else if (choice == '2')
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "\nEnter row number: " << endl;
                cin >> row;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "Enter column number: " << endl;
                cin >> col;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();

                if (row < MIN_ROWS || row > MAX_ROWS || col < MIN_COLS || col > MAX_COLS)
                    cout << "\nRow number must be between 0 and 14 and Column number must be between 0 and 19." << endl;
                else if (seats[row][col] != '*')
                    cout << "\nSeat is currently unavailable." << endl;
            } while (row < MIN_ROWS || row > MAX_ROWS || col < MIN_COLS || col > MAX_COLS || seats[row][col] != '*');

            seats[row][col] = '#';
            revenue += prices[row];

            tickets_sold++;
        }

        else if (choice == 'q')
            cout << "\nQuiting the program..." << endl;

        else
            cout << "\nInvalid selection." << endl;
    } while (choice != 'q');


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you reserve one of the seats around the edge (with row=MAX_ROWS or col=MAX_COLS), by any chance?

Comment: This is wrong: `if (row < MIN_ROWS || row > MAX_ROWS || col < MIN_COLS || col > MAX_COLS)` it should be `if (row < MIN_ROWS || row => MAX_ROWS || col < MIN_COLS || col => MAX_COLS)` since you allocate `char seats[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];` and c++ uses 0 based indexing meaning seats[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] is out of bounds.

Comment: I tried changing it to >= and <=, and I still get that error prompt when I try to quit my program.

Comment: your while() has the same issue `while (row < MIN_ROWS || row > MAX_ROWS || col < MIN_COLS || col > MAX_COLS || seats[row][col] != '*')`

Comment: Thanks, it didn't solve the problem I wanted, but it solved a problem I didn't know about!

Comment: Note: a double value is written as a value that contains a `.` and is not trailed by the character `f`.   I.E. the initializer for `revenue` should be: `0.0`.  While the `implicit conversion` feature of the language will (in most instances) correct that oversite.  it is a sloppy coding practice that you do not want to acquire.

Comment: regarding my above comment.  several if the values in the `prices[]` also need to be modified.  And if `MAX_ROWS` is 15 or greater, then the line: `revenue += prices[row];` can be accessing beyond the end of the `prices[]` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the "stack overflow" problem. You wrote some data out of the range of local variables.
Mostly you should check your operation on local arrays first.

In this case, your initialization of the array has a problem:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < MAX_COLS; rows++)
{
    for (int cols = 0; cols < MAX_COLS; cols++)
    {
        seats[rows][cols] = '*';
    }
}
```

The rows and columns were initialized by same macro MAX_COLS. And obviously MAX_COLS is greater than MAX_ROWS.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem! I can't believe I didn't see that -- that's a terrible checking error on my part.